# Get Hierarchy Level using T-SQL

Tags: sql, workflow

Sorry if my title is not right as I do not know how to explain my situation. I have just started a new web application which has a workflow on it. I have a table to store my workflow status.

**WorkflowStatus** table

```
Id |  Name
---|------------
1  |  Submitted
2  |  Accepted
3  |  Not Accepted
4  |  Returned for Re-Submission
5  |  Processed
6  |  Returned for Re-Acceptance
7  |  Completed
```

And I have another table to store all possible navigation for each of the status.

**WorkflowNavigation** table

```
WorkflowStatusId  |  NextWorkflowStatusId
------------------|------------------------
1                 |  2
1                 |  3
1                 |  4
2                 |  5
2                 |  6
5                 |  7
4                 |  1
6                 |  2
6                 |  3
6                 |  4
```

Now I am stuck on how to get the hierarchy level of the Workflow. I have tried to do the self join using **WITH** clause but it gave me an infinite loop because of the reversible flow. I only want to query out information like below from the WorkflowNavigation table (Basically, it is the clean version of the WorkflowNavigation i.e. without the reverse flow).

```
WorkflowStatusId    NextWorkflowStatusId
1                -> 2
2                -> 5
5                -> 7
1                -> 2
2                -> 6
6                -> 3
6                -> 4
1                -> 3
1                -> 4
```

And then I want to get some information like the below from the above query.

```
WorkflowStatusId  |  Level
------------------|-------
1                 |  1
2                 |  2
3                 |  2
4                 |  2
5                 |  3
6                 |  3
7                 |  4
```

Can anyone help me on the T-SQL query. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to traverse the graph from the first node.  Your graph has cycles, so you need a way where you don't revisit previous nodes.  The following approach uses a string to store the already visited nodes.  The query looks something like:

```
with g as (
      select wn.workflowstatusid, wn.WorkflowStatusId as nextws, 0 as lev,
             ',' + cast(wn.WorkflowStatusId as varchar(max)) + ',' as wses
      from workflownavigation wn
      where workflowstatusid = 1
      union all
      select g.workflownavigation, wn.NextWorkflowStatusId, lev + 1,
             ',' + cast(wn.NextWorkflowStatusId as varchar(max)) + g.wses
      from g join
           workflownavigation wn
           on g.nextws = wn.NextWorkflowStatusId
      where g.wses not like '%,' + cast(wn.NextWorkflowStatusId) + ',%'
     )
select nextws, min(lev)
from g
group by nextws;
```